# Pressing the Enter key instead of Clicking button with Shoes (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, shoes

As the title suggests, I'm just looking for a way of pressing a button in Shoes without clicking it.

I've searched the forum, but unfortunately can't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: I can definitely see why you'd prefer to use your fingers to press the ENTER key rather than have to lift your leg to click a button with your shoe. (Alas, I can't help you with your question, though!)

Comment: Lol, thanks! Not quite what I was after though.

Comment: Could you clarify: are you trying to click the button programmatically based on any other criteria/events, or are you trying to specifically have the Enter key work only when that button is focused?

Comment: So as an example, when you enter your details into a website, you type Username <tab> password <enter>

That's what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that won't work in red shoes under windows since the windows controlls steal all the events.
I managed to get this at work in green shoes under windows though.

Here an example

```
['green_shoes'].each(&method(:require))
Shoes.app{
  e = edit_line
  button("Click me!"){alert("You clicked me.")}
  keypress { |k| alert("You pressed Enter") if k == "\n"}
}
```

Grtz

Comment: Oh, do you have an example of how you did it with Green Shoes?

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example, sorry it took so long, forgot this thread, BTW, there is a new version of Green Shoes, check it out !

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I'll just have to re-write my app to use Green Shoes!

Answer (score 1):

I do not have shoes at the moment, but I believe you could trap the keypress and execute its action like so:

```
button('Click me') { do_something }

keypress { |k| do_something if k == '\n' }
```

From the manual:

> One caveat to all of those rules: normally the Return key gives you a
>   string `"\n"`.  When pressed with modifier keys, however, you end up
>   with `:control_enter`, `:control_alt_enter`, `:shift_alt_enter`